# fabric.js: How do I horizontally center fabric.Canvas() in the browser window?

Tags: javascript, css, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I want to use `fabric.js` so I convert canvas to be `fabric.Canvas`. However, this makes the canvas flush left rather than centered (using `fabric.js v1.6.6` and any modern browser, e.g., Safari, Firefox, Chrome). How do I center a `fabric.Canvas` horizontally in the browser's window?

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
var triangle = new fabric.Triangle({
  width: 40,
  height: 50,
  fill: 'blue',
  left: 50,
  top: 50
});
canvas.add(triangle);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.6.7/fabric.min.js"></script>

<div id="fabric_div" style="text-align:center">
  <canvas id="c" width="400" height="250" style="border:1px solid #ff0000"></canvas>
</div>
<p>Above is the fabric.canvas, and it appears flush left in the browser window.</p>
<p>Below is the regular canvas, and it appears centred horizontally in the browser window.</p>
<div id="regular_div" style="text-align:center">
  <canvas id="d" width="400" height="250" style="border:1px solid #00ff00"></canvas>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as you already have a fixed width for the object you can add `margin: 0 auto;` to the `.canvas-container` in your css like this:

```
<style>.canvas-container{margin: 0 auto;}</style>
```

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
var triangle = new fabric.Triangle({
  width: 40,
  height: 50,
  fill: 'blue',
  left: 50,
  top: 50
});
canvas.add(triangle);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.6.7/fabric.min.js"></script>
<style>
  .canvas-container {
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
</style>
<div id="fabric_div" style="text-align:center">
  <canvas id="c" width="400" height="250" style="border:1px solid #ff0000"></canvas>
</div>
<p>Above is the fabric.canvas, and it appears flush left in the browser window.</p>
<p>Below is the regular canvas, and it appears centred horizontally in the browser window.</p>
<div id="regular_div" style="text-align:center">
  <canvas id="d" width="400" height="250" style="border:1px solid #00ff00"></canvas>
</div>
```